# Jmeter Probably waiting for user to authorize the certificate

Tags: jmeter

All
When i am trying to record https urls with jmeter, i am getting below message in log:

jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.Proxy: [64432] Empty response to http over SSL. Probably waiting for user to authorize the certificate for XXXXXXX:443.

Its not loading any pages of our application.

Can anyone please help me how to resolve this issue?Thanks

Theju

Answer (score 0):

First read:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf
- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP%28S%29_Test_Script_Recorder

Among resolutions for your issue:

- Install in the browser as described in documentation the Fake Certification Authority created by JMeter
- Call https URL in the browser and accept certificate, then start recording your scenario

Answer (score 0):

Have you added JMeter's self-signed certificate to browser's exception list?

[image: Firefox Connection untrusted]

If so - try removing the certificate and starting over.

For other troubleshooting options and recommendations see [Recording HTTPS Traffic with JMeter's Proxy Server](https://blazemeter.com/blog/recording-https-traffic-jmeters-proxy-server) guide.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using [SmartMeter Recorder](https://www.smartmeter.io/blog/improve-jmeter-script-recording-introducing-smartmeter-recorder). You will avoid all isues with setting up the proxy. SmartMeter Recorder uses its own Chrome plugin and works out of the box. Read the article for more info.

Answer (score 0):

First of all for performance testing you should have application setup without the certificates otherwise you are testing results will differ. Your objective should be to test actual calls and those should be isolated.

If you still insist doing with certificate then you need to register JMeter certificate with browser which you are using for recording. You can find that in JMeter bin directory. Just register with your browser which you are using fir recording.